# Gem for websocket rails 2.0.2

Tags: javascript, websocket, comet, ruby-on-rails-2

I had implement a juggernaut server on rails 2.0.2 application and the implementation works fine in most browsers except firefox(though was > firefox 4) and also not working on the iphone and android . Is there any other gem which work on my rails application of any solution is available for the juggernaut server ?

PS. I cant upgrade my rails version as it will break application.